# Empty the entire neighbor div section

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two div sections `parent` and I want to empty its neighbor when I click on the button `keywordsubmit` in either divs`.parent`. But the following code isn't working:

```
   $('.parent').each(function() {    
    $(.keywordsubmit).click(function(e){         
      $(this).parent().siblings('#phpcom').empty();    
    });
   });
```

HTML code:

```
<div>

 <div class="parent">
  <select>
  <option>AAA</option>
  </select>
  <inputtype="text">
  <button type="submit" class="keywordsubmit">Submit</button>       
  <div class="area"></div>
 </div>

 <div class="parent">
  <select>
  <option>AAA</option>
  </select>
  <inputtype="text">
  <button type="submit" class="keywordsubmit">Submit</button>       
  <div class="area"></div>
 </div>

 <div id="phpcom">.............</div>

</div>
```

I have also tried `closest()`,`next()`, but it seems something is missing. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to empty just div with .parent class? #phpcom should stay intact?

Comment: @nevermind, I want to just empty #phpcom when clicking on the button in either `.parent` divs. The `.parents` should stay intact. None of the answers seems to be working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.keywordsubmit').click(function(){
   $('#phpcom').empty();
});
```

Comment: Thank you. I was complicating the issue.

Comment: Yes this is a good answer, but explainations would make it better.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/maju/mvRKp/)

```
$('.keywordsubmit').click(function(){
    greatParent = $(this).parents('.parent').parent();
    $("#phpcom",greatParent).empty();

});
```

Comment: It's weird because only the second button can find the neighbor div. The first one will hide the second button instead of `phpcom`

Comment: Are you looking at removing phpcom div ?
Like this 
http://jsfiddle.net/maju/mvRKp/

Answer (score 0):

Just do this:

```
$('.keywordsubmit').click(function(){
   $(this).closest('.parent').next().empty();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code , It may help you

```
$('.parent').each(function() {    
$(.keywordsubmit).click(function(e){   
$('.parent').hide();  
$(this).parent().show();  
});
});
```

Comment: Hi, can you show me a fiddle that it works, I can't get it to work in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g7FT2/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Use this [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ex9gt/)

```
$('.keywordsubmit').click(function(){
$('.parent').hide();
$(this).parent().show();
});
```